# Given the CDF of $X$, find the distribution of $X$ and $P(1 < X < 5)$

Tags: probability, distributions, cumulative-distribution-function

[image]

I know I have to find the distribution of X and then sum the probabilities of the values that apply the rule, but I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: How do you find PDF from CDF?

Comment: PDF is the derivative of CDF, so what I'm guessing should be the answer is 
$\int_1^2 \frac14 \,dx= \frac14$  + $\int_2^4 0 \,dx= 0$ + $\int_4^5 \frac16 \,dx= \frac16$

Comment: It might help to plot the CDF.

Comment: You may want to start with a refresher on calculus as the derivative of $F$ is not what is indicated in the comment. Note that a distribution is equally defined by the cdf and by the pdf, hence computing the later is not necessary, esp. for deriving $P(1<X<5)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite the probability of the event $a<X<b$.
We could consider the probability of $X$ being less than $b$ and then subtract the probability of $X$ being less than $a$. So at first, we are taking all the values of $X$ such that $X<5$, then we are excluding the values which are less than $1$. So $P(1<X<5)=P(X<5)-P(X<1)$.
By definition
$$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)\quad\text{ and }\quad P(X<a)=\lim_{n\to \infty}F_X\left(a-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
So you can write
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(1<X<5)&=&P(X<5)-P(X<1)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty}F_X\left(5-\frac{1}{n}\right)-\lim_{n\to \infty}F_X\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{5-\frac{1}{n}-1}{6}-\lim_{n\to \infty}F_X\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}}{4}\\
&=&\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{12}
\end{eqnarray*}
So you don't necessary need to use the PDF.
For a geometric intuition here is the plot of your CDF and its values in $1$ and $5$.[image]

Comment: With self-study questions (particularly ones that appear likely to be homework) it would be more usual to *provide hints and guidance* rather than numerical answers.

Comment: He showed me another approach for dealing with such problems. Though the guiding comments under my question did in fact help me come up with a solution.